# Schedul run Laravel 503 services unavailable error

Tags: php, laravel-8

I update the laradock and now my project is showing 503 error. Im not running any cron job.

[image]

Php version i have 8.1
Laravel 8
Node v14.17.0
NPM 8.1.3

I tried to install the composer, npm laravel roles permission, nothing worked.
Can't figure it out this error

```
(laradock) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: Can you run this command `php artisan up`

Comment: @LokendraSinghPanwar , i run 'php artisan up' this command, still showing same error 503.